# Parsing a string-what should be the end-index for the newline?

Tags: java, nsxmlparser, stringtokenizer

```
Your request for ...

Good morning Mr Praneel PIDIKITI
you have succ.....
```

This is my string i want to parse this string in order to get the value Praneel PIDIKITI 
i am using

```
  int begin_index = 0;
    int end_index = 0;

    String startkeyword = "Good morning";
    String endKeyword = " ???";
    int main_begin_index = lines[i].indexOf(startkeyword, begin_index);
    begin_index = main_begin_index;
    end_index = lines[i].indexOf(endKeyword, begin_index);

    String Name= lines[i].substring(begin_index + startkeyword.length(), end_index).trim();
```

What should be my endKeyword as it is the end of the line ???
can anyone help me ....

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `indexOf` for the `"Mr Praneel PIDIKITI"` String?

Comment: You already know that the string contains your name. Why not just extract it like what PaoloVictor suggested?

Comment: I'm guessing that the name isn't going to be the same every time

Comment: it's an example.. normally it should work with diff names too ..

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off using Regexp for this.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Good morning (.*)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line[i]);
    String name = "";
    if (m.find())
        name = m.group(1);
```